# PHP:: Upload with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload

I'm currently working on that script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$path="upload/";
$path=$path.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'],$path))
    {
        echo'The file '.basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']).' has been uploaded';
    }
    else
    {
        echo"There is an error";
    }
}

?>
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="384" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td width="108">Select File</td>
<td width="260"><label>
<input type="file" name="file_upload">
</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
<button id=clickToUpload type="submit" name="upload">Upload File</button>
</label></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's working as it should.

Now, I want to be able to do the same exact thing with jQuery...

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$('#clickToUpload').click(function(event)
{

event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "post.php",
      success: function(data)
      {

      }
});
});

</script>
```

This is my post.php page (as the same as in the index.php which was working)

```
$path="upload/";
$path=$path.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'];

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'],$path))
    {
        echo'The file '.basename($_FILES['file_upload']['name']).' has been uploaded';
    }
    else
    {
        echo"There is an error";
    }
}
```

But with ajax it seems like it's not working :(

What could possibly be the reason for that ?

Comment: Your AJAX call doesn't actually send anything to the server.

Comment: From firebug console : <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file_upload in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly include the form data with the call.

Try this:

```
var fd = new FormData($("form"));
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "post.php",
      data:fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data)
      {

      }
});
```